# How to update a HTML data-* attribute without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

i have a shopping cart icon with another icon over it that counts how many items are in the cart. Here's the code

CSS:

```
.fa-stack[data-contador]:after{
 position:absolute;
  right:-10%;
  top:-25%;
  content: attr(data-contador);
  font-size:70%;
  padding:.6em;
  border-radius:999px;
  line-height:.75em;
  color: white;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.85);
  text-align:center;
  min-width:2em;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-1x has-badge" data-contador="MY NUMBER">
   <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

I'm using the cart library from codeigniter and got this:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-1x has-badge" data-cantidad='<?= $this->cart->total_items(); ?>'>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-2x"></i>
</span>
```

> $this->cart->total_items(); returns the quantity of items

That works but only if i a refresh the page, my question is how to update that value without refreshing the page. Thanks

Comment: You have to triggers actions that update the cart and update your property "data-cantidad" with javascript (maybe with ajax or websocket if you need to update server-side)

Comment: No need for server-side update, so with AJAX it will be ok, but how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you are only using this for GUI purposes as client-side isn't to be trusted. That being said:

Controller:

```
function get_cart_items() {
    echo json_encode(array('item_count' => $this->cart->total_items()));
    exit();
}
```

JS:

```
//<span class="fa-stack fa-1x has-badge" id="cart-count" data-cantidad='<?= $this->cart->total_items(); ?>'>
$('.cart-add').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'path/to/get_cart_items',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#cart-count').attr('data-cantidad', data.item_count);
        }
    });
});
```

Note: `cart-add` is a *class* to be added to any buttons that trigger a new total (or an adding of an item to the cart). `cart-count` is an *id* to be added to the span/div with the `data-cantidad` attribute.

You will obviously have to include this js on any page that requires it as well as load jquery beforehand.

Comment: Yes, it's only for GUI purposes and works perfect! Huge thanks :)

Comment: I'm using Django, how to do this? I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woORrr3QNh8&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng&index=3 he made the button so you need to reload the page to get the new value. How can I changed it so it gives the new values, without reloading the page?